# What are the ways to protect system files against supply chain attacks (Windows)?

Tags: security, windows

There are a few general ways to fight off supply chain attacks which I'm not gonna go into now.
The purpose of this question is to discuss the last line of defense: file protection/encryption in case your file system getd compromised

If a malicious party got access to my windows PC and can list all the files and read their content, understandably, all my `keypair.jsons` are compromised as well (which us by design of file system wallets)

In case I still want to keep such files protected, which approach do I take on Windows?

Is **BitLocker** a reliable option? Do I rely on `sops` + `age` thing instead? Do I store sensitive files on a USB drive and keep them safe from the internet for the most part? Something else?